# Bug in the mdframed package (workaround?)

Tags: memoir, theorems, mdframed

I've discovered what appears to be a bug in the `mdframed` package. My goal was to use a package which allows me to create shaded theorem environments which span multiple pages (`thmtools` does not allow this). Run this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newmdtheoremenv{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\marginpar{\vspace*{9pt}\chapnumfont\thechapter}  % COMMENT IN/OUT

\begin{theorem}
\blindtext[2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\blindtext[3]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

When the marked line is commented out, then the theorems render as expected -- that is, the second theorem spans the first and second page. However, when the marked line is commented in, then the two theorems are generated on separate pages. The marked line simply adds in the chapter number on the side.

[image: Bad][image: Good]

Does anybody know the source of the bug? Moreover, is there a way to work around this? I want the theorems to span the pages, as the package was designed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't know exactly what's going on, I don't think it's a bug in `mdframed`, but a bad interaction of `\marginpar`. As a workaround you can use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newmdtheoremenv{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\marginnote{\chapnumfont\thechapter}

\begin{theorem}

\blindtext[2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\blindtext[3]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]